# Superscript ordinal numeral suffix in HTML code?

Tags: android, unicode

If `o` and `a` are available as superscripts in HTML, are ordinal numeral suffixes also available? I'm trying to implement an ordinal numeral suffix without having to create an extra string resource. TalkBack isn't saying what was expected for some reason.

String resource:

```
<string name="second">2\u207f\u1d48</string>
```

Talkback (expected result):

> "second"

Talkback (current result):

> "two-n-d"